# Syntax/Script to only select files created %date% (today) for batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

Created a batch file to go into our AutoCAD '.scr' files in a specific directory and that were created today. Im not sure if to do what i need, if i have to use FORFILES instead. The code works but not for files created today.

*Ive tried making arguments such as*

```
(%~ti :: FindSTR %DATE%)
```

*and as suggested in the comments:*

```
ECHO %~ti |FindSTR %DATE% && (echo today) || (echo other day)
```

to attempt too specify the date for the FOR command when looking for files to open and look for **.open** to replace as **OPEN Y**, but im not sure of the syntax OR where i can add it to the script.

The script seems to be going into all the files and saving even if the text DOESNT need to be changed, however changing it to only alter files that were created or last modified today would prevent that from happening.

```
 @echo off 
 setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

 FOR /R "V:\PPY005\CSC\Script Maker" %%S in (*.scr) DO (
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%%S" ^& break ^> "%%S" ') do (
         set "line=%%i"
         setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
         >>"%%S" echo(!line:.open=open y!
         endlocal
     )

 )
```

I need it to only apply to files created today as it would create some confusion as we manually load these and it would be confusing if one would load that was dated in the title such as 9-10-IMP-EM.scr and appear on top as if it was created/modified for today.

I need the directory listed as this batch will not be in the root directory of the files being changed and the script is looking for files in that directory of that specific file type, we prefer putting scripts in a special directory and just referencing them from that networked location such as opening a linked location from a document or using a batch file that will have a menu to select and run specific batch files referenced in (dont need help with that, i know how to do that)

I am kinda pulling out my hair with this as I cannot find documentation online on how to do this with the FOR command. Im a beginner so to say at Batch files, ive written several at this point but im not sure how to do this.

I understand that this MIGHT be easier to do via Powershell, but the company I work for doesnt allow us to use powershell for security reasons.

Comment: Please don't delete and repost questions. If you have new information to add to your question, edit it in.

Comment: The syntax for your first line would be: `echo %~ti |FindSTR %DATE% && (echo today) || (echo other day)`

Comment: @Stephan How exactly do i implement that? as putting that as the first line that crashes the script. where do i put that argument?

Comment: well, `%~ti` is a pseudo variable of the `for` command, so putting it inside a `for` loop would make sense. See `for /?` or [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/).

Comment: im having trouble. its not working and it keeps crashing the script. it says something about going into CMD and doing CALL /? or ECHO /? and reading through these isnt helping me. im not trying to display the date.  ive put it after either of the DO portions, ive put it after the %%S and before it, and everywhere in the parameters portion. I know ECHO is used to Display something but im not trying to display the date. am i just confused or was I not specific in what i was asking for @Stephan?

Comment: @Stephan  my %date% variable doesn't match the date that the `t` modifier outputs because the date variable also outputs the day of the week.  But I get where you are going with this.  If you can get them into a common variable that would make it quite easy to compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `FORFILES` command to select files based on the date. You can then parse the output of the `FORFILES` command with a `FOR /F` command that then nests right into your original code.

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN (
    'FORFILES /P "V:\PPY005\CSC\Script Maker" /M *.scr /D +0 /C "cmd /c echo @path"'
) DO (
for /f "delims=" %%H in ('type "%%~G" ^& break ^> "%%~G" ') do (
    set "line=%%H"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    >>"%%~G" echo(!line:.open=open y!
    endlocal 
)
)
```

Comment: I got a few errors 

Invalid attempt to call batch label outside of batch script x2 (this one went off twice after the :Process @Path")
 and it didnt change the text inside the files. 

I tried it exactly how you had it and it didnt work, then i altered it to use the proper GOTO commands i already have for the batch utility. 

https://0bin.net/paste/21L6gINMDSFYNz2x#B4nHADNkZ6m5CqPVDBJi8N7gVBwB0kteU0uVfzqiqTG


additionally this batch will be used every day, is there a ability to use %DATE% instead of a static date id have to change every day?

Comment: id like to add that i changed the path to TEST this and thats why the link has code that references a different path. and its not finding any files or changing the .open to Open Y in any of the files im testing with. and its also saying Invalid argument/option - ':Process' after i closed a ")" that i noticed that was open in the code.

Comment: @Daggerfella, I forgot about a limitation with the `FORFILES` command. You can't directly do a `CALL` to a label because it doesn't have access to the parent process.